# Drawing a pendulum's rotation over time in a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, bufferedimage, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I am trying to describe in a JPanel the evolution of a pendulum arm over time.
The pendulum has a fix node and the other node is calculated based on the fixed one and some angles fetched from a file. And every 1 second I expect to see the pendulum redrawn with new coordinates.
For the purpose of describing my issue, I have eliminated the file and the angle calculations and please consider that the mobile Point is saved into an ArrayList of Points.

I tried to achieve the gradual rotation over time by calling the drawRotatingLine() method from within the constructor of the RotateLine object.
In the drawRotatingLine() method I have a for loop which:

- sets the coordinates of the mobile Point based on the values of ArrayList of Points
- introduces a sleep of 1 second
- and calls the repaint() method

Trouble is that I only had my program draw the initial position and then the last one, the intermediary ones not getting painted.

The code is quite patchy having put it together from here and there.Please excuse me for having used abusively the BufferedImage, Graphics2D, and the calls to these objects in the paintComponent(...) method not being entirely clear to me, I just needed the program done and at this stage of my experience, I find quite intricate drawing on JPanels.

Below is the whole code:

```
public class RotateLine extends JPanel {

private static final int PREF_W = 600;
private static final int PREF_H = 600;
private static final int X1 = 100;
private static final int Y1 = 100;
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D bufferedGraphics;
private static ArrayList<Point> pointsList;
private static Point p;
private int counter = 0;

public RotateLine () {
    pointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    p = new Point(X1, Y1);
    int X2 = 400;
    int Y2 = Y1;
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        pointsList.add(new Point(X2, Y2));
        X2 = X2 - 100;
        Y2 = Y2 + 100;
    }
    image = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bufferedGraphics = image.createGraphics();
    drawRotatingLine();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    bufferedGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
    bufferedGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    bufferedGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
    bufferedGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    bufferedGraphics.drawLine(X1, Y1, p.x, p.y);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("clock");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new RotateLine());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void drawRotatingLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
        p.x = pointsList.get(i).x;
        p.y = pointsList.get(i).y;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Pendul.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        repaint();
    }        
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is common: you are calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread, which will put your entire application to sleep. Instead read up and use a Swing Timer. After you Google the Swing Timer tutorial, search this site for `Java Swing Timer Animation` for decent examples of how to use it for animation.

So,

- have your timer's delay be whatever time slice delay you wish the animation to have, although I recommend it not be < 12 msecs.
- In the Timer's ActionListener's actionPerformed, set the coordinates of the mobile Point based on the values of ArrayList of Points and an **index**
- Increment the index (very important)
- mod the index to maximal value
- call repaint

Answer (score 0):

Based on ***Hovercraft Full of Eels***'s answer, this is how I altered the initial code using the Java Swing Timer Animation:

```
public class RotateLine extends JPanel **implements ActionListener**{

private static final int PREF_W = 800;
private static final int PREF_H = 800;
private static final int X1 = 100;
private static final int Y1 = 100;
private static ArrayList<Point> pointsList;
private static Point p;
private int counter = 0;
private int index = 0;
**Timer time = new Timer(10, (ActionListener) this);**

public RotateLine () {
    pointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    p = new Point(X1, Y1);
    int X2 = 400;
    int Y2 = Y1;
    for (int count = 0; count < 300; count++) {
        pointsList.add(new Point(X2, Y2));
        X2 = X2 - 1;
        Y2 = Y2 + 2;
    }
    **time.start();**
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    drawRotatingLine(g2d);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("clock");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new RotateLine());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void drawRotatingLine(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, pointsList.get(index).x, pointsList.get(index).y);        
}

**public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  if (index < pointsList.size() - 1){
  time.setDelay(20);
  repaint();
  index++;
  }
}**
```